# MySQL return set if values don't exist

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, resultset, unique-values

Let's say I have 5 rows, containing the following:

```
ID     KEY       VALUE
1      address   123 Main Street
1      latlng    (111.139, 111.238)
2      address   45 South Street
3      address   67 North Ave
3      latlng    (448.002, 100.301110)
```

Now, if I wanted to return ONLY the row that did NOT contain a corresponding latlng row to accompany the address (ie, ID 2) how would I go about doing that with a mySQL statement?

This one has me stumped!!

Comment: I suggest that you make an attempt, then show us what you tried and what went wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE ID NOT IN
(SELECT ID FROM TABLE WHERE KEY = 'LATLNG')
```

Comment: Here's the query I ran, based on your answer:

    SELECT *
    FROM `datta`
    WHERE `key` = 'address'
    AND `id` NOT IN
    (SELECT `id` FROM `datta` WHERE `key` = 'latlng')

And I think that is going to do it! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try something like

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM Table t1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Table t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE t1.Key = 'latlng' AND t2.Key = 'address' AND t2.id IS NULL
```

Comment: I couldn't get this to work at all.